# Displaying data from data text attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am trying to display a text below the cube. The code works fine when I work alone in the fiddle,
but it does not work when I put it in my project.
Can you tell me how to display the `data-text="Cube1"` value?

Working code http://jsfiddle.net/PKwDp/4/

Not working code http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/EDKkg/1/

```
  $('document').ready(function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('.cubeCell').each(function () {
                    var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
                    $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyle">'+htmlText+'</div>');
                });
            }, 600);
            
        });


<div  data-text="Cube1" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png">testing</div>
```

Comment: There are no `.cubeCell` elements -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EDKkg/2/), so the loop never runs?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/EDKkg/3 i update the class but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your (non-working) example is that the element that has the `data-text` attribute doesn't have a `cubeCell` class.

This is the HTML you have in your jsFiddle:

```
<div  data-text="Cube1" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png">testing</div>
```

EDIT:

After your update to the jsFiddle, the text is now being added correctly. However, you can't see it, because it is hidden behind the cube itself.  But that's a CSS issue now, because your CSS is quite different than the working example.

EDIT 2:

You are missing the CSS for the `div.cubeTextStyle`. Your working example has it as:

```
div.cubeTextStyle {
  position: relative;
  top: 105px;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333 !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/EDKkg/3/ i update the class but still not working

Comment: Have you actually done any debugging? If you inspect the `cubeTextStyle` element, the text has been appended correctly now. You just can't see it in the preview, because the "testing" text is in the way.

Comment: At the very least, you seem to be missing the CSS for `div.cubeTextStyle`, which needs at least `position:relative;top:105px;` to work like the other example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use data attributes like this:

```
$(this).data('text').val()
```

Comment: I agree, this is the better way... however, the OP's approach should work too.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/EDKkg/3 i update the class but still not working